# Blue card registration from a different city

Tags: germany, blue-card, relocation

I got an offer from City A in germany with full remote work. I wanted to rent a house in City B and apply for blue card from City b. Can we do so? Or do I have to apply for bluecard from City A and then move to City B and update bluecard  address ?

This is the first time am moving to Germany with national visa.

Comment: Please add how long you have been working with the Blue Card, since the answer depends on the answer.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have updated.. this is the first tym am applying for bluecard.

Comment: If you already have the National visa, then the application has already been made and granted. The question is if the responsible Immigration Office is responsible for both cities, whereby it may not be important in which city you live in but only where the employer is.

Comment: Hmm.. employer is from City A, I wish to work from City B as its complete remote role

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can do so. As soon as one is going to work and not get social support from the state, he/she can live wherever he/she wants within Germany.

Just in case you would like to move between cities some time later:

After you register at new address, within several weeks your documents will be transferred to the immigration office of the new city.

Before registering at new address you can still apply for anything at the immigration office of your place of residence. From my personal experience, there should be no strict rules, you can just communicate with old/new immigration office on the personal level.

The only thing to consider is that **during** the transfer of documents it might be harder to apply for anything, so do it either before registering at the new address at the old office or one month after at the new office.