# Can I move to another German state before I got my electronic Blue Card?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have obtained the paperwork for the blue card, but I will need to wait up to eight weeks to receive the card itself. If I move to another state or city, will this affect the process? Do I need to provide my papers to the new city or just go through Anmeldung?

Comment: Will you be changing your employer?

Comment: No, the same employer but I need to live in another state

Comment: If you have something in writing about the change in the place of employment (including the date), you should send a copy to the present immigration office. They will either transfer your case file to the new office **or** tell you to report to that office after you have moved.

Comment: I will just change the place of living not employment at all

Comment: Then just inform the Immigration office of your new address,so that when the card is ready you be notified at you new address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blue card registration from a different city](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24188/blue-card-registration-from-a-different-city)