# Is it possible to apply for a German blue card while living in Germany in a different city from your company?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I've been living in Germany for a couple of years with the 'IT Specialist Visa'. At the moment **I do not have a blue card**.

I currently live in the same city where my company is located. But my company allows people to be fully remote as long as they reside within Germany.

I am planning to move to a different city in a few months, and since I now have all the requirements for a blue card, I would like to apply for one instead of renewing my Aufenhaltstitel under article 19c. I do not plan to change companies yet.

My question is: Is it possible to apply for the blue card even though I'm not living in the city where my company is located? Is some special requirement needed? I would be worried if I'm, say, located in Dresden and the authorities reject it saying the company's offices are located in Berlin.

**Note that this would not be a request to extend** my Aufenhaltstitel, it would be a first time application for a blue card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blue card registration from a different city](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24188/blue-card-registration-from-a-different-city)